# Upload large files on webpage?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, .net-4.0, httpruntime

We use the MojoPortal to a website and have some problems to upload files that is around 100 MB with the upload module. **(Pleas note that this has probably nothing to do with MojoPortal but with the ASP.NET and the IIS)**

The MojoPortal is set to use regular file Upload(not Neat Uploader) and to be able to upload big files we have set the following :

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="18000" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

And :

```
<compilation debug="false" defaultLanguage="C#" targetFramework="4.0">
```

**The problem** is that the upload will cacel after a couple of minuts (Aborted).

Is there any other values that I need to set to make this possible? The MojoPortal itself should not have any settings for this as far as I know so its regular ASP.NET 4.0.

BestRegards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're running this under IIS 7 or higher.
In this case you might want to update this property as well, in your web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="204800000"></requestLimits>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Yes I have tried this, and I have checked so the setting is set to override = allow. Is there anyother setting that would effect the upload size?

Comment: Hmm.. You have to have both the entry in system.web/httpRuntime and and system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits as far as I know. I'm currently also allowing users to upload large files and these are the only two settings I had to change, as far as I remember