# Uploading a file using fileupload control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I want to upload a file using FileUpload Control in asp.net and i'm using the following code to do that:

```
string filename1 = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
FileUploadControl.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\ExperimentForFolder\\" + filename1);
```

i also tried

```
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ExperimentForFolder\" + filename1);
```

But it is still freaking out. I don't understand what is wrong. Can you please help me.

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: may be **permission denied**?

Comment: @SLaks http://postimage.org/image/mh0rog4k/

Comment: That error might mean you try to upload big file.. try small simple text file of few Kilobytes.

Comment: @Shadow you are right !! How can i then upload large files ?

Comment: What IIS you have? Anyway, you need to change the configuration files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971071/upload-large-files-on-webpage

Comment: @Shadow maxAllowedContentLength is it bytes or Kilo bytes ? What is the measurement unit ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you need to save the file to your machine's Desktop?

Your ultimate option should be to use your Application Folder. It can be done like...

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/AppFolderName/" + FileName));
```

Comment: @Muhammad how can i get the application folder physical path? I understand using ~ (tilde) symbol would take you to the application root folder, but how can i access the file path (i mean full physical path to the file) again so that i allow users to download the component which was uploaded by me ?

Comment: Server.MapPath function is what you need. try to explore this method workoing.

Comment: @Muhammad how can i read the contents of the uploaded file and store in some string variable ? How can i do that ?

Comment: What do you mean by Contents ?  I not full understand your question.

Comment: @Muhammad Lets say i have uploaded a file with name ComponentDescription.txt which is a file with some explanation about the component uploaded. Now I want to open this ComponentDescription.txt file and read its contents and store in some string variable. How can i do that ?

Comment: yes, First of you have to put some app folder, then you can read the file using System.IO.File.Read(AppFolderPath);

Answer (score 1):

You need permissions over the place you store the file into... don't store in the server desktop.

Try this for start:

```
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filename1));
```

This will store the file in the same place as your `.aspx` file, if it works you can then create separate folder there then change the code to:

```
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("ExperimentForFolder/" + filename1));
```

Comment: How can i get the application folder full physical path ?

Comment: `Server.MapPath(filename1)` will return full physical path.